# Recursive function is causing a memory leak

Tags: php, sql

I'm fairly new to using php and wrote the following function in order to organize a simple comment thread.

```
function get_reply_comment($conn, $parentId, $marginleft)
{
  echo memory_get_usage();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parentId."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $output = '';

 if($parentId == 0)
 {
  $marginleft = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
 }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $output .= Stuff
  $output .= get_reply_comment($conn, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);
 }
 return $output;
}
```

I keeps getting a massive amount of memory usage. I thought results were called one at a time so where's the leak coming from?

Comment: This looks like you are creating an infinite loop since you are recursively calling `get_reply_comment()` from within itself

Comment: The loop should stop when there are no more comments in the table though

Comment: Are you getting any output or is it just throwing an error? What is the purpose of the recursion? Isn't it just running the same query forever?